# Unzip in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, zip, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have a zip file with the size of 32GB. I am required to import this to a data lake storage service account. I am trying to unzip and move the file through Azure data factory.

Zip file is uploaded to the Azure Blob Storage. However I cannot see the ZIP extension as the Source data format.

Is it possible to do the unzip operation through the data factory[image: AZ Data Factory]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Zip data set type, but you can Zip and Unzip using Binary data sets:

[image]

In the Copy activity, you can elect whether to retain the Zip file name as a folder:

[image]